# Allow some exceptions / special cases in the date validation with moment.js

Tags: momentjs

We use `moment.js` as our date validation, and it works great.
We also use it in custom Angular controls, with date format strings. Very difficult stuff, but easy with `moment.js`.

However, we run in the situation that we want to allow '00-12-1980' as input for our date control (read below if you want to know why), where 00 is the day, and 12 is the month. Also '00-00-1980' and '00-00-0000' must be valid. (or 00/00/0000 if the format string is D/M/YYYY, etc)

Now in `moment.js` these dates are marked invalid, and I also didn't find any way to check these dates with `moment.js` with some sort of addition "Yeah, I know 00 is weird for a daynumber, but just allow it". Or say `new moment('00-00-1980', 'D-M-YYYY')` and then ask "what is the daynumber?" to do some validation later myself.

So without moment, I have to do all the parsing (including date format strings) myself, and that is a lot of work, and error prone too. So my question is: can I somehow work with `moment.js` and also allow these kind of dates?

*So you wondered why we want to allow the odd dates of '00-00-1980'? It's becasue it's a search field, and the source system (official government sources) has these dates, from the goold old times when this input was allowed.*